# Do ℕ, \mathbb{N}, \BbbN, \symbb{N} effectively differ, and is there a "canonical" specification of the naturals?

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode-math, amssymb, blackboard

Continuing https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22167/, as far as I understand, all the four of `ℕ`, `\mathbb{N}`, `\BbbN`, `\symbb{N}` work now, and `\BbbN` is advised against.  Is there any reasonably default context (e.g., a self-constructed context that would redefine these macros and symbols wouldn't count) in which some of `ℕ`, `\mathbb{N}`, `\BbbN`, `\symbb{N}` produce different results than some others when using `amssymb`+`unicode-math`+`{xe|lua}latex`?  Compiling the example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[
  range={\setminus},
]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}[
  Extension=.otf,
  range={"2A3E},
  BoldFont=XITSMath-Bold,
]
\begin{document}
\(ℕ \mathbb{N} \BbbN \symbb{N}\)
\end{document}
```

with `xelatex`, e.g., I get visibly indistinguishable letters

> ℕℕℕℕ

I cannot distinguish them either when I put them as subscripts or superscripts.

Moreover, is there a consensus in the {xe|lua}[La]TeX world to name any of these ways as the ***standard*** way to denote the set of natural numbers?

(Of course, I leave aside the question whether the zero should belong to this set or not; it could flame up a war here and is up to the author anyway.)

Comment: Note that `amssymb` is redundant with `unicode-math`, although it should be harmless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### tl;dr

It's completely the same.

### Why do those four inputs produce the same output?

In `unicode-math-table.tex` we find

```latex
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02115}{\BbbN}{\mathalpha}{/bbb n, open face n}
```

Every Unicode code point relevant for math has a name, so that `unicode-math` can do, in this case, the equivalent of

```latex
\Umathchardef`ℕ = "7 "0 "02115
```

(the second number could change in case `range=bb` is used to select a different font for these characters).

If you add `\show\mathbb` to your sample TeX file (after `\begin{document}`), you'll get

```latex
> \mathbb=\long macro:
->\symbb .
```

This almost answers your question. At least we know that

1. typing `ℕ` or `\BbbN` is the same
2. typing `\mathbb{N}` or `\symbb{N}` is the same

It only remains to discover what's the relationship between the two cases above. Simple: `\symbb{N}` does `\BbbN`. Not really by chaining `N` to `Bbb`, but something like that (it's more complicated because one can use `range=bb` to use a different font for blackboard bold letters).

Now we know that typing

```latex
$ℕ \BbbN \mathbb{N} \symbb{N}$
```

is exactly the same. The alias name `\mathbb` for `\symbb` is for backwards compatibility with older code.

Some explanation is in order. `unicode-math` used to have just `\mathXX` commands. However, it was realized that distinguishing between `\mathXX` and `\symXX` is necessary. The first form is about words used in math, the second form for single characters (and doesn't enforce ligatures if used for more characters in a row); these forms can point to different fonts. Typically, for instance, `\mathbf` will use the boldface text font, whereas `\symbf{x}` will use `\mbfx`, pointing to U+1D431 in the math font.

While the distinction is necessary for boldface, in the case of blackboard bold there is no usage of it as a text font, so no distinction is made between `\mathbb` and `\symbb`, by default. You (or a package) might redefine `\mathbb` to do something else (not that I recommend it).

### What's the preferred form?

I'd avoid `\BbbN` and probably prefer `\symbb` for newer documents, unless it's possible to directly type in `ℕ`.

Comment: @user49915 Yes, indeed. Let me fix it: I copied the first match, but didn't notice the case.

Answer (score 15):

The difference is mainly historical.  `\BbbN` was created for the original `amsfonts`, pre-LaTeX; it should be considered obsolete now.
(Oops!  @egreg points out in a comment that `\BbbN` has been defined for `unicode-math`, so I was thinking of `\Bbb{N}`.  *That* surely should be considered obsolete.)
The original LaTeX equivalent is `\mathbb{N}`, and should still be reliable.

`\symbb{N}` was defined for fonts developed after the blackboard bold alphabet was added to Unicode.

The symbol itself (which I can't represent because it's not available on the aged laptop I'm using) depends on having a utf-8 capable input device, and is not available for pdflatex, which is still limited to 8-bit input.

All forms are equivalent, and the one you use depends on which flavor of LaTeX you're using.  There may also be some restrictions associated with the publisher, if you're submitting your document for publication.

This may not give an unambiguous answer to your question, but it should give you some idea of how the development of the blackboard bold fonts and their support affects the decision of which should be used in what circumstances.

Comment: `\BbbN` is a specific command in `unicode-math`. The command `\Bbb` (with an argument) is obsolete.

Answer (score 12):

If you modify your file to have

```
\showoutput
\(ℕ \mathbb{N} \BbbN \symbb{N} \showlists\)
```

Then you get

```
\mathord
.\fam0 ℕ
\mathord
.\fam0 ℕ
\mathord
.\fam0 ℕ
\mathord
.\fam0 ℕ
### horizontal mode entered at line 20
```

Four identical N, same font and same math class (mathord).

I would say use `ℕ` if you like Unicode input and `\symbb{N}` if you prefer ASCII TeX command markup. So they are the preferred forms, but as they are all the same thing it doesn't matter much which you use.

Of course other font setups may make things differ. In general `\symxx` will give you characters from the same font using the math alphabet ranges, whereas `\mathxx` might do that or might (as in classic tex) use a different font.

Comment: I'd use `\mathbbm` of the `bbm` package for all blackboard bold letters: clean, nice, slender. Blackboard bold is nowhere bold on the blackboard, this is why we simply double some of the lines. `\mathbb N` makes the slanted line bold.

Comment: @MátéWierdl bbm font is OK if it fits with the overall font design but if you use unicode-math  `\symbb` then the blackboard bold N comes from the same font as the normal N and is chosen by the font designer to match.

Comment: I see, @DavidCarlisle.  How do I access `\symbb` in pdflatex?

Comment: @MátéWierdl `\symbb` is `unicode-math` so just xetex or luatex, the whole point of `\symxx` commands is that they access the math alphabets from the same font, position 8469 in the case of ℕ that can not mean anything in pdftex which has at most 256 characters per font, and most math fonts only have 128 characters

Answer (score 1):

One difference is that ℕ and `\BbbN` (as well as `^^^^2115`) work in either math mode or text mode, but behave differently.  If you have a text font selected that contains the Unicode character, using them gets you the glyph from the current text font, with the current text style, such as `\textbf` or `\textit`.  For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setmathfont{DejaVu Math Tex Gyre}

\begin{document}
ℕ
\end{document}
```

Both `\symbb{N}` and  `\mathbb{N}` only work in math mode.